# NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API

Tags: java, ant

I got the following warning when I try to build my project with ant. My build.xml ist a auto-generated from eclipse:

```
warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

In Eclipse there is no error at the line and if i remove the line (are annotation for hibernate) the error will occur in another line. It seems to be that the error comes in the first line of my java file.

I tried to replace hibernate and the annotations with an new version as well as javax persistence. But nothing helped.

I hope someone else has the same failure and knows what i need to do.

EDIT:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="myclass")
public class MYCLASS implements Cloneable {
```

The second row generates the warning. But if i remove the row the next will generate the same warning. If i remove all annotations the last line generates the warning.

Comment: Could you tell us which task, and which code, generates this warning?

Comment: can you post section of ant which is showing Warning?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say this is like a deprecation warning.

Comment: see post below was the solution for my problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you importing `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException` somewhere?.
Sun classes are not part of the official Java API and may get changed/removed at any time without notice. Apart from that, they might be missing if someone runs your application on a different JVM than the Oracle one. For example the IBM JVM does not have access to the sun classes and therefore your program would fail at runtime.

Comment: To build on this, a good alternative would be `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: thank you. that was the solution! in one file there was an import of sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException which i don't need...